# Match column in 2 CSV files and display output in third file

Tags: perl

I have 2 CSV files, file1.csv and file2.csv . I have to pick each row of column 3 in file1 and iterate through column 3 of file2 to find a match and if the match occurs then display the complete matched rows(from column 1,2 and 3)only from file2.csv in a third csv file.My code till now only fetches the column 3 from both the csv files. How can I match column 3 of both the files and display the matched rows ? Please help.

```
File1:

Comp_Name,Date,Files
Component1,2013/04/01,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/newfile.txt;
Component1,2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile24;
Component1,2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile25;
Component1,2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile26;
Component1,2013/04/25,/Com/src2;

File2:

Comp_name,Date,Files
Component1,2013/04/07,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/newfile.txt;
Component1,2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile24;
Component1,2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile25;
Component2,2013/04/23,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/newfile.txt;
Component3,2013/04/27,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile24;
Component1,2013/04/25,/Com/src2;

Output format:

Comp_Name,Date,Files
Component1,2013/04/07,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/newfile.txt;
Component2,2013/04/23,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/newfile.txt;
Component1,2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile24;
Component3,2013/04/27,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile24;
Component1,2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile25;
Component1,2013/04/25,/Com/src2;
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1 = "C:\\pick\\file1.csv";
my $file2 = "C:\\pick\\file2.csv";
my $file3 = "C:\\pick\\file3.csv";

my $type;
my $type1;
my @fields;
my @fields2;

open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file1)  or die "Could not open file '$file1' $!"; #Throw error if file doesn't open
while (my $row = <$fh>) # reading each row till end of file
{  
chomp $row;  
 @fields = split ",",$row;
 $type = $fields[2];
 print"\n$type";     
 }

 open(my $fh2, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file2)  or die "Could not open file '$file2' $!"; #Throw error if file doesn't open
 while (my $row2 = <$fh2>) # reading each row till end of file
 {  
 chomp $row2;  
 @fields2 = split ",",$row2;
 $type1 = $fields2[2];
 print"\n$type1";
 foreach($type)
  {
  if ($type eq $type1)
  {
  print $row2;
  }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Edited my code to compare column 3 in both csv but it doesn't give the required output.just prints any random line from file 2.

Comment: Hi, could someone help, where I am doing wrong in my code ?

Comment: I don't understand, why doesn't testfile25 match or src2?

Comment: updated the output. It will included testfile25 and src2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a matter to over complicate.. I would personally use a module `Text::CSV_XS` or as mentioned already `Tie::Array::CSV` to perform here.

If you're having trouble using a module, I suppose this would be an alternative. You can modify to your desired wants and needs, I used the data you supplied and got the results you want.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh1, '<', 'file1.csv' or die "failed open: $!";
open my $fh2, '<', 'file2.csv' or die "failed open: $!";
open my $out, '>', 'file3.csv' or die "failed open: $!";

my %hash1 = map { $_ => 1 } <$fh1>;
my %hash2 = map { $_ => 1 } <$fh2>;
close $fh1;
close $fh2;

my @result = 
      map  { join ',', $hash1{$_->[2]} ? () : $_->[0], $_->[1], $_->[2] }
      sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] || $a->[2] cmp $b->[2] || $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }
      map  { s/\s*$//; [split /,/] } keys %hash2;

print $out "$_\n" for @result;

close $out;

__OUTPUT__
Comp_name,Date,Files
Component1,2013/04/07,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/newfile.txt;
Component2,2013/04/23,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/newfile.txt;
Component1,2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile24;
Component3,2013/04/27,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile24;
Component1,2013/04/24,/Com/src/folder1/folder2/testfile25;
Component1,2013/04/25,/Com/src2;
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your response.I got compilation errors while executing the code. The errors are in the rows corresponding to 'my @result'.Compilation errors are:Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) ,Use of uninitialized value in string comparison (cmp) , Use of uninitialized value in join or string and Use of uninitialized value in hash element . To overcome this I declared my $a and my $b in the  beginning but then it throws error: Can't use "my $a" in sort comparison. What can I do to correct this ?

Comment: Ok, I did this. Rest all error is gone but it still shows one compilation error : Use of uninitialized value in hash element at same line but Hash values are already declared as we see that.

Comment: No, this gives again the compilation error: Use of uninitialized value $c in hash element.

Comment: I think some declaration issue with hash values only.its not identifying $a,b or c when we put values inside hash.

Comment: I got it fixed.Not sure what worked as I made only simple change like declaring all the variables at beginning.Anyways,with the 2 options you mentioned in comment it works half way as it doesnot display the order correctly for first line of file2.For second line, it displays fine.(It displays newfile.txt,test24.txt,text24.txt and then newfile.txt) The code mentioned in your Answer gives me the desired output but also throws the compilation error for date(eg: Argument "2013/04/24" isn't numeric in numeric comparison (<=>))  How can I remove this compilation error ?

Comment: I replaced the line with this: sort { $a->[2] cmp $b->[2] || $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] } and it looks to be working now. Doesn't show the date compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for a hash ( my %file1)

so instead of continually opening the files you can read the contents into hashes

```
@fields = split ",",$row;
$type = $fields[2];
$hash1{$type} = $row;
```

I see you have duplicates too so the hash entry will be replaced upon duplication

so you can store an array of values in the hash

```
$hash1{$type} = [] unless $hash1{$type};
push @{$hash1{$type}}, $row;
```

Your next problem is how to traverse the arrays inside hashes

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not sure if I completely understood as I am new to perl. Can something be done using my code and taking it further ? My query is more on how to compare column 3 in both the csv files for each row  of column 3 in file 1 and display the matched row of file 2.Even if its duplicated it needs to be displayed.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can compare strings using eq  `if ($type eq $type1){ print ...;}` but you do need to address reading the file multiple times

Comment: I have edited my code to compare but still not giving the required output. It just prints any row in random from file 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using my [Tie::Array::CSV](http://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aCSV) module. It uses some clever Perl tricks to represent each CSV file as a Perl array of arrayrefs. I use it to make an index of the first file, then to loop over the second file and finally to output to the third.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::Array::CSV;

tie my @file1,  'Tie::Array::CSV', 'file1'  or die 'Cannot tie file1';
tie my @file2,  'Tie::Array::CSV', 'file2'  or die 'Cannot tie file2';
tie my @output, 'Tie::Array::CSV', 'output' or die 'Cannot tie output';

# setup a match table from file2
my %match = map { ( $_->[-1] => 1 ) } @file1[1..$#file1];

#header
push @output, $file2[0];

# iterate over file2
for my $row ( @file2[1..$#file2] ) {
  next unless $match{$row->[-1]}; # check for match
  push @output, $row; # print to output if match
}
```

The output I get is different from yours, but I cannot figure out why your output does not include `testfile25` and `src2`.

Comment: Thanks. Well, the output will definetly include testfile25 and src2 as well. My mistake I should have updated the output for all the files. How does your output differ ? I actually need the output in the way I have mentioned. Also, updated the output now.

Comment: I was trying to run your code but ran into this error for Tie function: Can't locate Tie/Array/CSV.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl
64/lib .) Any idea, how can I fix this ?

Comment: Probably I need to use CPAN perl to fix this first.

Comment: I got CPAN installed but it still doesn't work. getting the error: Can't locate Tie/Array/CSV.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib
C:/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/lib .)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean you "got CPAN installed"? CPAN is a huge collection of modules, the CPAN.pm module is a CPAN installer/client. Using the client you can install other modules; try invoking `cpan Tie::Array::CSV` with permissions if needed, this should install the modules you need.

Comment: I installed the module now.The code runs but I get this error 'CSV combine error' at line push @output, $file2[0];

Comment: That error comes from Text::CSV which can be a little persnickety, especially on windows (are you on windows?). Still it is well documented and widely used, I'm sure you can figure it out. It works for me :-)

Comment: Now I get a new error 'CSV parse error EIF - Loose unescaped quote' at line my %match = map { ( $_->[-1] => 1 ) } @file1[1..$#file1];

Comment: Did you search the documentation for keywords? `allow_loose_quotes` sounds apt.